# How would you implement the method System.Type.IsEquivalentTo in C# .Net previous than 4?

Tags: c#, .net

What is an equivalent implementation of the method [`System.Type.IsEquivalentTo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isequivalentto(v=vs.110).aspx) that reproduces the same internal logics in C# .Net 3.5 or older?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=IsEquivalentTo) and go from there. Looking at the [base implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,5e094dddad8bc001) there seems to be nothing exciting going on. There may be more [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtimehandles.cs,12d6d84d105ceba3) but that's as deep as the rabbithole goes on `referencesource.microsoft.com` I guess.

Comment: From the source, it looks like it simply calls the `==` operator, which is marked as `MethodImpl.InternalCall`.

Comment: @hvd `making this answer fairly useless` OP didn't state the exact class that would be using the derived function so unless you have a crystal ball answering that question your guess is as good as mine. The pointer to the referencesource (and _all_ `IsEquivalentTo` methods) should help OP out in the right direction.

Comment: @RobIII I commented because of the initial version of your answer, which merely linked to the base class implementation, and deleted my comment when I noticed you expanded your answer.

Comment: @hvd My [initial answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35454334/1) *still* contained 1) a link to referencesource.microsoft.com and 2) all implementations of IsEquivalentTo().

Comment: @RobIII It's well-documented that revisions made within the first five minutes after posting an answer don't show up in the edit history. Are you claiming you didn't make any changes in those first five minutes? I won't be able to disprove that, but I do distinctly recall clicking on the only link in your answer and being sent only to the base class implementation. Or did I somehow manage to click on the next page without noticing?

Comment: @hvd " _Are you claiming you didn't make any changes in those first five minutes?_ " I don't recall explicitly but even if it were (which is a good possibility) it _still_ would've had 1) the referencesource to show OP and 2) a link to a (specific implementation of) IsEquivalentTo, maybe not all. So you're saying we need to teach people how to use a search-box once we show them where to look? It also _still_ holds that OP didn't mention any derived type; actually OP _specifically_ asks for `System.Type.IsEquivalentTo` which, you claim, I linked to. Where's your problem man? What did I do?

Comment: Thank you guys for the help. Please don't go flame.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of .NET Framework, two distinct types are never equivalent, so the whole method doesn't make sense. If the method returns `true` for two distinct COM types, it's supposed to indicate that you can cast from one of those COM types to the other (because in the COM world, they're the same type). Prior to .NET 4, you simply can't do that, you'll get an exception.

Depending on what you're after, you can either inspect the types' GUIDs (which won't help you get any conversion working), or use `==` for comparison (which indicates two different COM wrapper classes are not the same type).